# Hiding some form elements according to the selected dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

I wanted to hide the elements of the form according to the selected dropdown menu in that form. I succeed to hide the fields according to that particular field. But when I try to update that particular record, it again load the page with all the fields with entered data. But I need to again select the same menu again after which I get that fields hidden again. I am using PHP for this functionality.

I think it's because I am using on change function of jQuery. Here is the code for that function:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#viewpage').on('change',function(){

        switch(this.value){
            case '1':
                $('.Song').show();
                $('.Videos').hide();
                break;
            case '2':
                $('.Videos').show();
                $('.Song').hide();
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

Is there any other function that I can use instead of change function that works almost similar way but give me the required fields only, whenever I try to update that record. also change when I change the option.

-- **The question before this line is solved. Needed solution for the question after this line** --

Also I have some fields that I don't required in 'songs' viewpage like 'story_description', but set "required => true " in my Model. So even I am hiding that field for 'Song', I need to put some default values into it. How can I add the default values, either in my index.php or in 'controller.php'.

here is my piece of code from index.php where I am hiding that element.

```
 <div class="form-group vid_field" <?= $option != 2 ? "" : "style='display:none'"  ?>>
                <label>Description</label>
                <?php echo $model->Form->editorFor("description"); ?>
 </div>
```

Here is my controller file piece of code:

```
 function update_post()
 { 

    parent::update_post();
 }
```

I think code for setting default values must be go in controller file. Like we can check if the page selected is Song, than the default value for Description must be="XYZ". I don't know how can we do that. Help appreciated. TIA

Comment: It isn't clear what is going on and what you want to achieve. There seems to be a lot of code missing. PHP, HTML, etc. Also, please give a better flow of the things you want to happen.

Comment: You can trigger the change event by using `$('#viewpage').change();` after you defined the `on` event. This then will use whatever the `select` is set too and adjust on page load. Granted you need to use php to 'select' the correct 'option' in the `select` menu during output.

Comment: When your page gets re-loaded, you need to set the selected value to the previously selected item so change will fire.

Comment: By using ajax you can prevent the page from reloading when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the page from loading like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#viewpage').on('change',function(event){

event.preventDefault();

switch(this.value){
        case '1':
            $('.Song').show();
            $('.Videos').hide();
            break;
        case '2':
            $('.Videos').show();
            $('.Song').hide();
            break;
    }
})
```

});

Comment: Your `.preventDefault();` here has nothing to do with stopping page loading. If anything it can conflict with the default behavior of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic to a separate function, and call it after pageload (not only when the change event fires). You could also do `$('#viewpage').change();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateView($('#viewpage'));
});

$('#viewpage').on('change',function(){
    updateView($(this));
});

function updateView(elem) {
    switch(elem.val()){
        case '1':
            $('.Song').show();
            $('.Videos').hide();
            break;
        case '2':
            $('.Videos').show();
            $('.Song').hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('#viewpage')` might not exist yet depending on where he puts his javascript. Binding events to elements should go inside `$(document).ready` (so the whole dom is ready before trying to locate and bind events).

Comment: Edited my question, actually added question, would like to know if you can help me out with that @BalázsVarga

Comment: It isn't clear what framework you use, but Form->editorFor should have an attribute for default value. In html you can simply do `<input value="XYZ"` to define a value, but you could also use `placeholder="XYZ"`. This way you don't associate a value with the field, so you need to check it on validation (accept or change empty values).